# Why is $\{p\}\times W$ is a subspace of $T_pS$, and equal to it (S an affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$)?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

I am having trouble with the following example of tangent space. I guess the book is treating tangent vectors as tangent to curves for this part, so I am trying to make sense of it accordingly

**Tangent space to an affine subspace**

Let $S$ be an affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (which is the translation of a vector subspace $W$). The tangent space at a point $p$ of $S$ is $\{p\}\times W$.

In fact, every $(p,\nu) \in\{p\}\times W $ is tangent at $0$ to the curve $p+t\nu$ of $S$, so $\{p\}\times W$ is a subspace of $T_pS$, and therefore $\{p\}\times W$ coincides with $T_p S$

**Can someone tell me if the following arguments are correct or explain to me how to do it?**

1. why is every $(p,\nu) \in\{p\}\times W$ is tangent at $0$ to the curve $p+t\nu$?

Let $\alpha(t)=p+t\nu$, so $\alpha'(t)=\nu$ and $\alpha'(0)=\nu$ . Furthermore $\alpha(0)=p$ So every element of $\{p\}\times W$ is actually a tangent vector $\alpha'(t)$ to the curve $\alpha(t)$ of $S $at $0$ : $(p,\nu)=(\alpha(0), \alpha'(0))$

2. how does it follow from here that $\{p\}\times W$ is a subspace of $T_pS$?.

If the previous argument is correct, if every element of $\{p\}\times W$ is a tangent vector to a curve of $S$ of the form $\alpha(t)=p+t\nu$ and if $T_pS$ is the set to all tangent vectors, that is to, any curve in $S$ (not only the ones of the form $\alpha(t)=p+t\nu)$, then $\{p\}\times W \subset T_pS$

3. If $\{p\}\times W$ is a subspace of  $T_pS$, why should they be equal?

Since $\{p\}\times W \subset T_pS$, and they are both vector spaces, so $\{p\}\times W$ is a subspace of  $T_pS$ and since they have   the same dimension it follows that they are equal

Comment: What is the definition of $T_pS$ that you have?

Comment: @ArcticChar Let M be an n-manifold T_pM is the set of tangent vectors at p. A tangent vector $\nu$is a $\mathbb{R}$-linear mapping $\nu: C^{\infty}(M)\to\mathbb{R} $ such that $\nu (fg) =(\nu f)g(p)+f(p)\nu g$

Comment: @J.C.VegaO Add this to your question, it is an essential information.

Comment: Where does this come from? From a textbook or a lecture? The elements of $\{p\} \times W$ are certainly not tangent vectors in the sense of your definition.

Comment: @PaulFrost It comes from a textbook, but it is not in the same section. So the first time T_pS is defined is done as in my previous comment, later they say that to each applied vector it is associated the directional derivation. Then they introduce  tangent vectors to curves which are linear combination of derivations,  $\alpha'(t_0)=(\alpha'(t_0)x^k)\frac {\partial}{\partial x^k}|_p$, so I guess it is again a directional derivation. So in this sense they are still complaint with the initial definition, aren't they?

Comment: There are various different (but equivalent) definitions of $T_pM$. It is essential that you specify which you want to use in your question. One approach is based on curves, but derivations and curves are different things. And an element of $\{p\} \times W$ is neither a curve nor a derivation. But you can establish canonical bijections. I encourage ypu to edit your question. Otherwise I can't imagine that you get answers.

Comment: @PaulFrost I edited, and tried to answer the question, could you check if it makes sense?

Comment: Which textbook do you use?

Comment: @Paul Frost It's an old italian book my professor used to learn the subject , only a pdf exists that my professor gave me. The author is Rotondaro